# MSDTC Transaction Issue in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, transactionscope, msdtc

I am working on WCF Client Server application , keeping both on separate machines.
I am a bit aware about DTC issues because of TransactionScope when we run cient and server on different machines, so I resolved it for different clients and server by doing follow.

1. Setting Security settings for DTC including Outbound settings in Client and Inbound on Server.
2. Keeping firewall totally turned off (For making my side safe for now)

All the clients and server are working properly except one machine.

I have checked,

1.Security settings
2.Firewall => Off
3.Same Guid issue
4.Restarting DTC
5.PingDTC (That I already tried and dnt want to use again coz not at all user-friendly tool)

every possibility I found from Google, but this machine only having error.
In both the case if I make it client or Server, it can not communicate with another machines, and rest all are ok with each other.

Can anybody please suggest me proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting MSDTC is quite a pain.

Is the problem machine the same operating system as all of the others?  I have found that XP, Vista, 8, and Server 2012 don't work without putting in a registry key at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\RPC\ { RestrictRemoteClients, DWORD, 0 }
```

You will probably need to create the RPC key, it's normally not there by default.

Generally, even though DTCPing is quite an awkward tool to use, it has proven invaluable for me every time I have some unfathomable reason why MSDTC isn't working.  If the above doesn't work, can you post the error messages you get from DTCPing?

Comment: Yes the OS are same, and its Win 7. Even I had tested this one also, none other client has this folder ans they all are still working. Even putting this key into this faulty machine's registry is not working. Any other idea?

Comment: Generally I would use DTCPing and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx to identify what the actual problem is, it has always sorted things for me in the past.  Sorry I can't be of more assistance.